# delete image from server folder

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is code of uploading image in my localhost/file/img folder and also inserting image path and name in my table.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
  if (count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0)
    {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++)
      {
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      if ($tmpFilePath != "")
        {
        $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        $filePath = "img/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath))
          {
          $files[] = $shortname;
          $query = "insert into images(id,img_name) values('$file_id',' $filePath')";
          mysqli_query($con, $query);
          }
        }
      }
    }

  echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";
  if (is_array($files))
    {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($files as $file)
      {
      echo "<li>$file</li>";
      }

    echo "</ul>";
    }
  }

?>
```

**Table Images** with attribute **img_name** type is **LONGBLOB** 
now its totally working fine but when i am  deleting image from database its getting error that image name is not found. here is code of sending image id and image name using a href

```
<ul>
  <a href="index.php?img_id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>&img=<?php echo urlencode($img); ?>" 
    style="color:red; margin-left:18px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')" >Delete
  </a>
</ul>
```

now here is code of want i want to delete from my database and  also from my localhost folder named img .

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['img_id'], $_GET['img']))
  {
  $id = $_GET['img_id'];
  $img = $_GET['img'];
  $query = "delete from images where id='$id' and image='$img'";
  if (mysqli_query($con, $query))
    {
    unlink($img);
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Image Deleted successfully")';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("image does not exist")';
    echo '</script>';
    }
  } 
?>
```

now showing warning that img/image_name.jpg not found.Help me please .

Comment: try to debug you query by echo and then run this in mysql

Comment: That's some horribly unindented code

Comment: If you are deleting the file refence in database maybe you should to delete the file in the server. Otherwise, your server will have junk files that are not being used.

Answer (score 2):

I think your delete query is wrong

```
if(isset($_GET['img_id'] , $_GET['img'])){
$id=$_GET['img_id'];
$img=$_GET['img'];
$query="delete from images where id='$id' and image='$id'";
}

$query="delete from images where id='$id' and image='$img'";
```

In this query you check Id and Image field with same $id variable

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
      $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $tmpname1 = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $exten = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
      $exten = $exten[1];
      if ($exten != '') {
        $image_name = "img" . time() . "." . $exten;
      }

      move_uploaded_file($tmpname1, FCPATH . 'assets/admin/uploads/' . $image_name);
      $query = "insert into images(id,img_name) values('your_id',' $image_name')";
      mysqli_query($con, $query);
//see your code
/*
$id=$_GET['img_id'];
$img=$_GET['img'];
$query="delete from images where id='$id' and image='$id'";
*/
```

you pass the same id value for image. you should try this-

```
$query="delete from images where id='$id' and image='$img'";
    }
```